# Why is adding org.apache.spark.avro dependency is mandatory to read/write avro files in Spark2.4 while I'm using com.databricks.spark.avro?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc, spark-avro

I tried to run my Spark/Scala code 2.3.0 on a Cloud Dataproc cluster 1.4 where there's Spark 2.4.8 installed. I faced an error concerning the reading of avro files. Here's my code :

```
sparkSession.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(input)
```

This code failed as expected. Then I added this [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-avro_2.12/2.4.0) to my `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-avro_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Which made my code run successfully. And this is the part that I don't understand , I'm still using the module `com.databricks.spark.avro` in my code. Why is adding `org.apache.spark.avro` dependency solved my problem, knowing that I'm not really using it in my code?

I was expecting that I will need to change my code to something like this:

```
sparkSession.read.format("avro").load(input)
```

Comment: I guess what happened was that "com.databricks.spark.avro" is now just an alias of "avro" for backward compatibility.

Comment: @Dagang I'm not sure I understand your comment

Comment: It is important to add the correct dependencies in your `pom.xml` file. Because this file contains information about the project and configuration details used by Maven to build the project. The dependency that you are using `org.apache.spark` is needed to load/save data in Avro format, you need to specify the data source option format as `avro` or `org.apache.spark.avro`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is historic artifact of the fact that initially Spark Avro support was added by Databricks in their proprietary Spark Runtime as `com.databricks.spark.avro` format, when Sark Avro support was added to open-source Spark as `avro` format then, for backward compatibility, support of the `com.databricks.spark.avro` format was retained [if `spark.sql.legacy.replaceDatabricksSparkAvro.enabled` property is set to `true`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.2.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/DataSource.scala#L643-L644):

> If it is set to true, the data source provider com.databricks.spark.avro is mapped to the built-in but external Avro data source module for backward compatibility.

Comment: That does explain it :) Thank you Igor  for your answer